# GTK DBus equivalent to QDBusConnection

Tags: rust, gtk

I'm using GTK 4 and Rust and I'm looking for the equivalent of QDBusConnection. Specifically, I want to connect to org.freedesktop.UDisks2 and have a signal fire when a drive is added or removed. In Qt I could do the following:

```
QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect("org.freedesktop.UDisks2", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2", "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager", "InterfacesAdded", this, SLOT(my_func(QDBusObjectPath,InterfacesAndProperties)));
```

How can I accomplish this using GTK? Any language is fine as I can adapt it to Rust (Gtk-rs).

Comment: Have a look at [`gio::DBusConnection`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/gio/struct.DBusConnection.html) (which links to examples in C).

Comment: I've been playing around with gio::DBusConnection but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out, especially when it comes to creating a signal. Any chance you can point me to an example? The only example I've found is in the Gtk-rs documentation but it's more of a guide (in C) and it's difficult to follow.

Answer (score 4):

This minimum example program should get your signal on the debug output:

```
use gio::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let dbus = gio::bus_get_sync(gio::BusType::System, gio::Cancellable::NONE).unwrap();
    let udisks2 = gio::DBusProxy::new_sync(
        &dbus,
        gio::DBusProxyFlags::NONE,
        None,
        Some("org.freedesktop.UDisks2"),
        "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2",
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager",
        gio::Cancellable::NONE
    ).unwrap();
    udisks2.connect("g-signal", true, |x| {
        dbg!(x);
        let signal_name: &str = x[2].get().unwrap();
        println!("signal '{signal_name}'");
        let args: glib::Variant = x[3].get().unwrap();
        let n = args.n_children();
        for i in 0..n {
            let v = args.child_value(i);
            println!("    {i}: {v}");
        }
        None
    });

    glib::MainLoop::new(None, false).run();
}
```

The funny thing about `gio::DBusProxy` is that all the dbus signals are notified through the same single `g-signal` glib-signal.

In this signal, the `args` argument is a `&[glib::Value]` with 4 arguments:

0. The `DBusProxy` value itself.
1. A string with the peer bus name.
2. A string with the name of the signal.
3. A tuple variant with the signal parameters.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. What is `x` in that code? If I copy & paste this I get  `cannot find value `x` in this scope`

Comment: @RickyKresslein: Silly me! `x` was `args` before I renamed it to copy/paste into the answer. Fixed now, I think.

Comment: Okay, this is almost perfect. It works and I can see when a drive is connected or disconnected. However, I'm creating a GUI and it never shows up because it is stuck in this loop. Is there any way to make the plugging and unplugging of a drive ("InterfacesAdded" and "InterfacesRemoved" signals) a normal GTK signal, similar to a button's `clicked` signal, so it activates a function on interfaces being added or removed?

Comment: @RickyKresslein: For every `*_sync` function there is a similar async function that does the same thing but that gets the result as a callback. But I think that you may get stuck in the `MainLoop`, I added that because this is a standalone executable; if you use Gtk you already have a main loop, just remove this line.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think this is the answer I'm looking for, but I might not have enough knowledge to make it work for me. I can't figure out how to make it work without using the `MainLoop` portion. I understand that I have a "main loop" in GTK, but plugging and unplugging a drive does not print anything unless I use the `MainLoop` line.

Comment: @RickyKresslein: Just guessing here, but maybe because you are dropping the `DBusProxy` object: if you do not keep a reference to this object around, it will be destroyed and its signals will stop working. Doing the loop thing will stall your program in that function and prevent the drop.